# Replacement for xargs -d in osx

Tags: macos, xargs

In Linux, you can use `xargs -d,` to quickly run the `hostname` command against four different servers with sequential names as follows:

`echo -n 1,2,3,4 |xargs -d, -I{} ssh root@www{}.example.com hostname`

It looks like the OSX xargs command does not support the delimiter parameter. Can you achieve the same result with a differently formatted `echo`, or through some other command-line utility?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about:

```
echo {1..4} | xargs -n1 -I{} ssh root@www{}.example.com hostname
```

From `man xargs`:

```
-n number
Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for each invocation of utility.
```

Comment: If the values can contain spaces, linefeeds, or tabs, you could use something like `printf 'a\0a' | xargs -0 -n1 echo`.

Comment: this doesn't work with gnu xargs, ie, all of debian `https://asciinema.org/a/jfqOwiRpH6IFGZDrPTo0qQTNf`. Shame! Shame! ;)

Comment: as a bonus, you can also add `-P n` which will parallelize it. Since it's all IO, this can be helpful. So, `-P 4`

Answer (score 71):

Alternatively, you can always install GNU `xargs` through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and the GNU `findutils` package.

Install Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Follow the instructions. Then install findutils:

```
brew install findutils
```

This will give you GNU `xargs` as `gxargs`, and you can use the syntax you're accustomed to from GNU/Linux. The same goes for other basic commands found in the findutils package such as `gfind` or `glocate` or `gupdatedb`, which have different BSD counterparts on OS X.

Comment: Thank you! I did this, then added the path to my `.zshrc` (as explained in the installation output) so I wouldn't have to use the `g` prefix.

Comment: ha yiss exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `tr` in OSX to convert the commas to new lines and use xargs to enumerate through each item as follows:

```
echo -n 1,2,3,4 | tr -s ',' '\n' | xargs -I{} ssh root@www{}.example.com hostname
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it run in parallel, use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ssh root@www{}.example.com hostname ::: {1..4}
```

Comment: xargs does with with `-P`

Answer (score 1):

with printf

```sh
$ printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 4 | xargs -I{} echo ssh root@www{}.example.com hostname
ssh root@www1.example.com hostname
ssh root@www2.example.com hostname
ssh root@www3.example.com hostname
ssh root@www4.example.com hostname
```